# Dataintegrity between tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add data integrity between columns in different tables in SQL Server?
I have table Pay with column *Date* and table Orders with column *DateofOrder*. And I would like to add the data integrity so the *Date* cannot be earlier than the *DateofOrder*. 
And when the user insert there the same date or even earlier database would show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you mean something like this, here done with a trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pay ON Pay
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * 
        FROM [Order] o
        JOIN inserted i
        ON o.id = i.payment_id
        WHERE DateOfOrder>[date])
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('Sorry, Dave', 16, 1)
  ROLLBACK;
  RETURN;
END

INSERT INTO [Order] values (1, GETDATE());               -- Order today
INSERT INTO Pay values (1, DATEADD(dd, -1, getdate()));  -- Pay yesterday
> Sorry, Dave
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using **[INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089.aspx)** Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an INSTEAD OF or AFTER trigger to enforce this, you can't do it declaratively. Well you could use a check constraint with a TVF or something but I've never tried that.

I'd show sample code but I'm not sure what payroll has to do with orders. If a new order comes in, what pay date must be later than or equal to the order date? Is there some other column that relates these two tables?

Comment: First I insert into Order the date eg. 2012-03-11 and then I go to Pay table and insert date eg. 2012-03-15 (of course it can be 2012-03-11) but it can't be the 2012-03-01

On my classes we only use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Can you show me the sample code of my problem? And let's say that Order and Pay are the only tables in database with only DateofOrder and Date columns.

Comment: If you can explain how your tables are related, I might be able to take a shot. Do you mean when you insert an order there can be no earlier date in the pay table at all, or no earlier date for a row that has something at all to do with the order you just inserted?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without resorting to triggers.

The idea is to add the `DateofOrder` in the `Orders` table to its existing key -- let's call it `order_id` -- to create a compound superkey, then reference this superkey (rather than the simple key solely `order_id`) in the `Pay` table.

Here are the bare bones:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
 order_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 DateofOrder DATE NOT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (order_id),  -- simple candidate key
 UNIQUE (DateofOrder, order_id)  -- compund superkey
);

CREATE TABLE Pay
(
 order_id CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
 DateofOrder DATE NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (DateofOrder, order_id)
    REFERENCES Orders (DateofOrder, order_id), 
 DateOfPayment DATE NOT NULL,
 CHECK (DateofOrder < DateOfPayment), 
 UNIQUE (order_id)
);
```